# TestFlight version says ""The requested app is not available or doesn't exist." in Flutter SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

I have created a Flutter Application. I have used Xcode Version 13.1.

I have created all the certificates that are necessary for the development and distribution. Previously I have uploaded around 5 builds for which I have invited the internal and external users as Testers. Those builds are working fine for the testing.

From build no 6 I started facing this strange issue "The requested app is not available or doesn't exist."

I tested the build before it is being uploaded in the TestFlight. It's working fine and also the app moves to Ready to Submit status as well.

From the 6th build i just upgraded my Flutter SDK version to 3.0 and later downgraded this and tried the build.

I tried with a different build by varying the plist data, but nothing works for us. I checked on my mac for the various certificates for this application and they are all good and valid.

I don't understand why for this application I have this behaviour.

Step that i have done:

1. I built the app.
2. I tested it on my iPhone.
3. From Xcode, I made an archive and uploaded it to TestFlight.
4. The archive has been received by Apple. It was then processed by Apple.
5. And finally, I received a notification that it was available on TestFlight.
6. While downloading the app it shows this error message.
7. But the build is there in the TestFlight.

Someone would have any idea?

Comment: Having the same, any idea?